# List all additional jars loaded in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I want to see the jars my spark context is using.
I found the code in Scala:

```sh
$ spark-shell --jars --master=spark://datasci:7077 --jars /opt/jars/xgboost4j-spark-0.7-jar-with-dependencies.jar --packages elsevierlabs-os:spark-xml-utils:1.6.0

scala> spark.sparkContext.listJars.foreach(println)
spark://datasci:42661/jars/net.sf.saxon_Saxon-HE-9.6.0-7.jar
spark://datasci:42661/jars/elsevierlabs-os_spark-xml-utils-1.6.0.jar
spark://datasci:42661/jars/org.apache.commons_commons-lang3-3.4.jar
spark://datasci:42661/jars/commons-logging_commons-logging-1.2.jar
spark://datasci:42661/jars/xgboost4j-spark-0.7-jar-with-dependencies.jar
spark://datasci:42661/jars/commons-io_commons-io-2.4.jar
```

Source: [List All Additional Jars Loaded in Spark](http://bailiwick.io/2017/08/11/list-all-additional-jars-loaded-in-spark/)

But I could not find how to do it in PySpark.
Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I really got the extra jars with this command:

```
print(spark.sparkContext._jsc.sc().listJars())
```

Answer (score 5):

```
sparkContext._jsc.sc().listJars()
```

`_jsc` is the java spark context

Comment: How do I unpack this object? All that listJars() is returning for me is "JavaObject id=o30"? It doesn't appear be iterable or have any methods that can be seen via introspection?

Comment: @AdamLuchjenbroers when you `print` the object, it shows the jar filename: `print(spark.sparkContext._jsc.sc().listJars())`